# jQuery to show a div and hide another div at the same time. Purpose to browse a 5 div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Assume there is a book which has various chapters (say 5) in it. Complete book is present in a single html page with all 5 chapters in it. 
Each Chapter is some html content and is present inside a div with a class name called chapter. You can take any dummy HTML content for each of the five pages with  tags in it as Chapter 1, Chapter 2 ..... and Chapter 5.

Now when the page opens the first chapter is shown to the user. Which has Chapter 1 in the heading. The single chapter is bigger than the height of the window so user can scroll to read this chapter. But once the user reaches the end of the chapter the user can not see or scroll to the next chapter.

When the user is at the end of the chapter he sees a button at the bottom right saying go to the next chapter. 
Imp:- This button can not be the part of chapter HTML it has to be generated programmatically at the end of the chapter via js.

When the person clicks on this button the next chapter (chapter 2 in this case) should scroll up from the bottom automatically till the top pushing the first page out of the window. So the whole screen then should be covered by chapter 2 shown with the animation by pushing chapter 1 above.

So at a given time user can only see one chapter by scrolling up or down. He will have to click the buttons to access the next or the previous chapter.

Similarly for Chapter 2 there will be a button at the top of the page to go to chapter 1 in which the Chapter 1 will come from the top pushing Chapter2 down completely out of the window. And for chapter 2 there will also be a button at the bottom of the page clicking on which user will be taken to chapter 3 in the similar animation format.

This is a sort of interaction that the user will have while reading the book.

Comment: So where's the code? Can you post a live demo of what you got so far?

Answer (score 0):

U dont need to write a lot of code. Try the jquery's accordian plugin http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Yes .. m trying since yesterday... have found this feature in some new websites too... but couldn't get it!Thanx for replying.

Comment: U wand the code? The examples are not helpfull enough on the site?

Comment: Examples are helpful.. Thanx... Actually i needed it urgently. My xams are goin on and so I couldn' give much time to it!

Answer (score 0):

jquery-ui API has given a very good documentation and examples for accordion [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/)